# Getting Internal system error when requesting

Tags: api, error-handling, wso2, fault

I have written an API in wso2. On sending request to it I am getting error as follows:

```
{"responseCode" : "001", "responseDesc" : "Internal system error"}
```

Any idea what does this mean and why is this error coming?

Below is the fault sequence that is running here.

```
<faultSequence>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="ERROR_CODE"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_DETAIL" name="ERROR_DETAIL"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="ERROR_EXCEPTION"/>
    </log>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format> { "responseCode" : "$1", "responseDesc" : "$2"} </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <respond/>
</faultSequence>
```

Comment: What do you see in the wso2 logs? We can't really tell anything by looking at the fault sequence.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons, the fault sequence is triggered from your main sequence, so you need to figure out what's happening there.  The ERROR_CODE = 001 doesn't seem to be something WSO2 generates unless you are setting it somewhere. So most probably this seems to be coming from the Backend.

Comment: Can you please check the updated version I have added the fault sequence which generating

Comment: As mentioned by @ycr WSO2 does not generate this kind of error codes and error messages. This seems to be coming from the back end service itself. Please check your back end service.

Comment: You can enable wire logs and see the response received from the backend.